# How to do update Delete method using CodeFirstApproach and ViewModel in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I want to do update delete Process using Code First approach and view model in mvc4.I had create the view and i done insertion process using Code First approach and ViewModel because my DB is fully normalized and i used EF .so I used code first approach and ViewModel. Now I complete the **Insertion process** . Now I want to know how to do **Update** and **Delete** process using Code First approach and ViewModel. Please any one give me the solution..

**My Model**

```
 public class CustomerModel1
    {
        public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string PrintName { get; set; }
 }

public partial class ContactModel
    {
        public System.Guid ContactID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string PrintName { get; set; }
        public string Mobile1 { get; set; }
        public string Mobile2 { get; set; }
        public string Phone1 { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        public string Email1 { get; set; }
         public string Website1 { get; set; }
}
```

**My VieModel**

```
  public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ContactID { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo1 { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo2 { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo1 { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo2 { get; set; }
    public string Website1 { get; set; }
 }
  public class VisitorsEntities1 : DbContext
{

 public DbSet Customer    { get; set; }
 public DbSet Contact { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
  return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(CustomerViewModel viewmodel)

  {
     var Customerobj = new Customer()
        { 
         CustomerID= Guid .NewGuid (),
         DisplayName = viewmodel.CustomerName,
         PrintName = viewmodel .CustomerName
   };
    var Contactobj = new Contact()
        {
            ContactID= Guid.NewGuid(),
            DisplayName= viewmodel.CustomerName,
            PrintName=viewmodel.CustomerName,
            Mobile1=viewmodel.MobileNo1,
            Mobile2 = viewmodel.MobileNo2,
            Phone1= viewmodel.PhoneNo1,
            Phone2=viewmodel.PhoneNo2,
            Email1=viewmodel.Email1,
            Website1=viewmodel.Website1

            db.Customer.Add(Customerobj);
            db.Contact.Add(Contactobj);
            db.SaveChanges();
       return View();
   }
```

Here i complete the insert process  using **CodeFirstApproach** and **ViewModel**. Insertion is working fine. Now I want to do Update ,Delete and Details (Index) Process . How to do that using code first approach and ViewModel...

Thanks

Comment: Update: Almost the same thing you did. You will receive the new values as a parameter in your controller. Fetch the user by some Id field than set the new values and call SaveChanges. To delete, pass an Id, find that user and call delete on your context.

Comment: please elaborate user answer Jpgrassi . Fetch the user means what you are mentioning  here .

Comment: Check Mattew's answer. Though, this is pretty standard, with a simple google search you would be able to find your answer. Try harder next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an Update action that takes the model as a parameter, and save the changes:

```
db.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Then add a Delete action that takes the item's id as a parameter and deletes:

```
 Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
 db.BlogPosts.Remove(contact);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Actually, if you are using Visual Studio, it should be able to generate all of these actions automatically for you, which you can then modify as needed.